# How to get all values from all textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitableview

After googling this issue i managed to do this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"InsertMarksCell";
    SaveAllExamMarksForAllStudentsTableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    StudentPersonalInfo *newStudentName = feedItemsNow[indexPath.row];

    myCell.txtStudentMark.text = @"hello";
    myCell.txtStudentMark.delegate = self;
    myCell.txtStudentMark.tag = indexPath.row;

    return myCell;
}
```

this code i this sets the textfield " txtStudentMark " delegate and sets it's tag ...

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField * ) textField
{
    NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:55] text];
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
}
```

i keep getting null value using the NSLog Function

i have a textField in a custom cell which the user will fill with data and i need to get all data from all textfields, am i going the right way ?

from what i understood, i need to set the tag for textField and set it as delegate, then i can call textfield by tag to get the text in it .

how can i make this work ?

Comment: If `text` is `nil` then that means either `self.view` is `nil`, or `self.view` doesn't have a subview with a tag of 55.

Comment: i have a tag of 55 ... and i already filled the textfields with "hello" , just edited the code and added it, all the textfields have "hello" text . the textfields are declared in the @interface SaveAllExamMarksForAllStudentsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
how can i call the textfield ?

Comment: textfield is a subView of the tableViewCell ? right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField * ) textField
{
    NSString *text = [textField text];
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
}
```

?

Your problem is that you are adding textfield into cell, but ask view for this tag.

EDIT:

to get your textfield from tableview

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField * ) textField
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.view.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:55 inSection:0]];

    NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:55] text];
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
}
```

Comment: Nice , Works and prints all values once done editing ... However , can i call the textfield by TAG ?

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [self.view.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:55 inSection:0]];

at the " self.view.tableView " i can't set it to my tableView self.view.StudentsNameIDMarksTableView

error :
property StudentsNameIDMarksTableView not found on object type UIView

Comment: @jack, only via your tableview, because your textfield is placed inside content view of your cell. See my edit. View hierarchy looks like  uitableview - uitableviewcell - contentview - your_textfield. I can miss some of tempoeal views, but order is the same as i mentioned

Comment: @jack,  use self. StudentsNameIDMarksTableView

Comment: using the self. StudentsNameIDMarksTableView , i get Null value, also i changed the tag to 0 instead of 55 since the " indexPath.row has to start from 0 so i know the tag0 will exist , but still null value ...

Comment: what is this "indexPathForRow:55" what value should i have ?

Comment: @jack, did you connect via outlet your tableview and property in code?

Comment: also, try [cell viewWithTag:0], according to this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html  it should work

Comment: yes i did, i am setting data from mysql server to the tableview setting " name and ID " self.StudentsNameIDMarksTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.StudentsNameIDMarksTableView.delegate = self;

Comment: Am i setting the tag properly with this ? "myCell.txtStudentMark.tag = indexPath.row;"

Comment: @jack, it depends on how you set datasource. if you returned count of array in numberOfRowsInSection - my answer YES

Answer (score 0):

@Doro thanks for the help.

since the problem is solved, this is the answer that worked well for me

to get the row number and data in the textfield by TAG

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField * ) textField
{
    // here get the tag number which is the row number
    NSInteger *rowNumberWithout200 = (long)textField.tag;
    NSString  *myRow = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", rowNumberWithout200];
    NSLog(@"row %@",myRow);

    // get the text in the cell with the required tag...
    UITableViewCell* myCell = (UITableViewCell*)textField.superview;
    NSString *StudentMark = [(UITextField *)[myCell viewWithTag:textField.tag] text];
    NSLog(@"mark %@",StudentMark);
}
```